# How to turn IEnumerable to string array of combined values

Tags: c#

Lets say I had my object:

```
public class MyObject{ public p1; public p2; }
```

And the enumerable version:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects;
```

How would I turn it into a `string[]` that would be an array of `p1 + '=' + p2` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some simple linq on it

```
(from m in MyObjects
select m.p1 + "=" + p2).ToArray()
```

if you don't really need it as an array you can omit the call to `ToArray()` and you'd then have an `IEnumerable<string>` instead

If you wish to put them all into a comma separated list you don't need to transform to an array since the `string.Join`method has an over load that takes an enumerable. So you can do this:

```
string.Join(",",from m in MyObjects
                select m.p1 + "=" + p2);
```

I personally prefer the above syntax but if you are all for using fewer letters then the code is semantically equal to the below shorter snippet

```
string.Join(",",MyObjects.Select(m => m.p1 + "=" + p2));
```

Comment: Thanks. Now to turn it into a CSV string, I can just `String.Join()` that.. Or could it all be done in the first linq operation?

Comment: Why do you use `string.Join`, mine its `String.Join`. Is it because my version? (2013)?

Comment: in C# there's no difference

Comment: Well one it turns blue, the other turns green. I get an error if i do `string.Join`

Comment: I'm using C# version 4, not sure if that matters, anyway thanks again

Comment: All aliases are by default blue in VS (int, string, double etc)whereas if you use the actual type name (System.Int32, System.String, System.Double etc) they are green but they are exactly the same type

Answer (score 0):

`MyObjects.Select(o => o.p1 + "=" + o1.p2).ToArray()`